# Making Tags with SourceTree

Tags: github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

How can we tag code in BitBucket ? I've looking in the documentation but I could not find any way of doing this using GUI or a client like SourceTree. Is this possible only using command line ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the Tag-Action in SourceTree for that, see the screenshot.

[image: Tagging in SourceTree]

Comment: Damn I don't how I missed that , May be I had the window smaller than the total toolbar width.

Comment: Why are the tags so limited in character validation and no description available? I want a tag "v2.0 iOS app store review point"